# How to Return message as true from jquery dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to show Confirmation message buttons as "Yes" or "No", for that i am showing jquery dialog box as

```
function ConfirmDialog(message) {
    $('<div></div>').appendTo('body')
        .html('<div><h6>' + message + '?</h6></div>')
        .dialog({
        modal: true,
        title: 'Message',
        zIndex: 10000,
        autoOpen: true,
        width: 'auto',
        resizable: false,
        buttons: {
            Yes: function (e) {
                $(this).dialog("close");

                return true;
            },
            No: function () {


                $(this).dialog("close");
                return false;
            }
        },
        close: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
};
```

But my requirement is when i click "Yes" it should return as true like

```
var msg = ConfirmDialog("Are You Sure , Do you want to Delete all items??");

if (msg == true) {
    alert("you clicked yes");

} else {
    alert("you clicked No");
}
```

For that , i have return as true, but script is not working like, and one more is I can't write script in "Yes" button function, due to some issues, please help me anyone.

Comment: You can't `return` from inner anonymouse function to outer function `directly` !

Comment: you can't do that because of the async nature of the dialog

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-undefined-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-canonical

Answer (score 4):

You can't 'return' anything from a dialog box. Instead you should have a function which you run based on the button clicked in the dialog, something like this:

```
.dialog({
    // other settings...
    buttons: {
        Yes: function (e) {
            $(this).dialog("close");
            dialogResult(true);
        },
        No: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
            dialogResult(false);
        }
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a confirm() like functionality which is directly browser supported and custom  implementation of it is not possible.
What you really have to do is put your code in click event of 'yes' and 'no' button.

```
$('#btnYes').click(function(){
alert("you clicked yes");
}); 

$('#btnNo').click(function(){
 alert("you clicked No");
});
```